# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "S"

Tags: java, integer

I get this error when I try to use Integer.parseInt() with a single char.

```
String s = "s";
System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
```

Is what gives me the error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "S"
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret This gained a bit of popularity via [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/52qv6h/when_you_have_been_staring_at_your_code_for_so/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The letter `S` is not a number. Did you mean to write the number 5?

```
String s = "5";
System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
```

Or did you mean to print the ASCII or Unicode value of the character `S`?

```
char s = 's';
System.out.println((int) s);
```

Comment: How do I parse to int it if mystring="No" and the function returns an int? because for me parseInt(mystring) throws NumberFormatexception....

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt(String s)` is used to convert integers in string form like `"42"` to value they represent in decimal. Use `String.charAt(0)` if you want first character.

Answer (score 1):

yes of course..
Integer.parseInt can make the integer representation of only numeric strings.Try:

### String s="98"

Answer (score 0):

To parse an string to a number you must have valid number into the string.

Here your S is not a number.

```
String s = "s"; System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
```

It should be something like this:

```
String s = "100";//or whatever integer you want to parse.
System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is nothing to do with single or multichar value. A simple test of this is that, if you remove the ' (quotes) from the value, would you find a Integer?

If no, the `Integer.parseiInt()` is bound to fail.

I would recomend you to go for really quick and short tutorial located at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm